# cannot connect php odbc to sqlserver 2005

Tags: php, sql-server-2005, odbc

I would like connect from PHP to SQLServer 2005 by ODBC, but i was not ok.

I have created DNS in control panel already.

Please tell me the solution, why cannot connect ?

I have connected from php to Sqlserver2008 was ok.

```
Code

odbc_connect("test2", "test2","12345") or die("Fail");

Connection fail
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use mssql_connect().

You can see the user contributed comments here .http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php

Comment: i dont want to use my mssql connect. can you give me a solution.

Comment: May I ask why you dont want to use?

Comment: $connection = odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=$yourserver;Database=$yourdb;", $user, $password);

Comment: it not working.$connection = odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=$yourserver;Database=$yourdb;", $user, $password);

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this url http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_db_odbc.asp
That might help you out.

Comment: And what does it print when you execute it?

Answer (score 0):

`$cxn = odbc_connect("ODBC_DSN_NAME", "", "");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM some_table'";
$res = odbc_exec($cxn, $sql);`